# How to print x pattern in Java using for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop

My goal is to get this output when input is 3:

```
  *     *
   *   *
    * *
     *
    * *
   *   *
  *     *
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void PrintX (int number) {
 for (int i = 0; i <= (number * 2 + 1); i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j <= (number * 2 + 1); j++)
       {
           if (i == j) 
           {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
           else if (i + j == (number * 2 + 2))
           {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.print(" ");
           }
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

My output when input is 3 is like this and I'm not sure why there is the extra star at the top.

```
*
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
```

Comment: Walk through the code by hand or a debugger. Consider what happens when i=0 and j=0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set `i = 1` inside outer for loop. Compile and run the example below:

```
    public class TestPrintX {
        public static void PrintX (int number) {
         for (int i = 1; i <= (number * 2 + 1); i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j <= (number * 2 + 1); j++)
               {
                   if (i == j) 
                   {
                       System.out.print("*");
                   }
                   else if (i + j == (number * 2 + 2))
                   {
                       System.out.print("*");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   }
               }
               System.out.println("");
           }
        } 
        public static void main(String arg[]) {
            PrintX(3);
        } // end of main method
} // end of class
```

Comment: Are you going to provide any explanation as to what was wrong and what you changed?

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. int i = 1 instead of int i = 0

Comment: @mo sean, don't force the OP to accept, no 'should' here.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy this answer helps him so it should be accepted.

Comment: Just because a user accepted the answer doesn't mean it is a good answer or meets the sites rules. It can still be downvoted for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop would work as you expect if you set an initial `i` value of `1`. However, you could also make this a little shorter. First, consider storing the `number * 2 + 1`. Then you might combine a few lambda expressions with `IntStream`. Basically, you want to map each possible index to a `" "` or a `"*"` - so

```
public static void PrintX(int number) {
    int len = number * 2 + 1;
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, len).forEachOrdered(i -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, len)
                .mapToObj(j -> i == j || i + j == len + 1 ? "*" : " ")
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```