# how do i draw an ''x'' shape using atericks with a given size w/ a nested for loop?

Tags: java

My code is only printing out a straight line and i am at a blank. Can someone explain to me how i would do this project?

```
public class assigment04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 5;

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int column = 1; column <= size; column++) {
                if (row == column || column == (size + 1 - row)) {
                    System.out.println("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the desired output would look like?

Comment: I should think the desired output would look sort of like.....an **X**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print x pattern in Java using for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552089/how-to-print-x-pattern-in-java-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three errors in your code:

- you print a line feed after each `*`
- you print a line feed after each character, not every row
- [off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) which cause `*` to be printed at incorrect positions

Here is the corrected version:

```java
public class assignment04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 5;

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
                if (row == column || column == (size - row - 1)) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ javac assignment04.java 
$ java assignment04
*   *
 * * 
  *  
 * * 
*   *
```